# Soap Webservice parse Typo3 Links for iPhone UIWebView

Tags: php, iphone, soap, uiwebview, typo3

Currently I am working on an iPhone Application, which loads the Data from the company's website and Database, so I wrote a webservice with soap to load the data.

The Website has been created (not from me) as a Typo3. Now when loading the Data, I have problems with links inside the content. Most of them are just Links to a PDF. 
Since Typo3 is storing the links in a different way in the content, I have to parse them to my webservice, so that the iPhone can display them correctly...

Is there a php class out there which parses Typo3 links back to html links?

Does anyone of you have any experience in this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the SOAP interface? Or do you need to parse the Links within iOS?

Comment: I do not have access to manage the typo3. The Soap was written by myself... so Yes I do have access to that... my soap is connecting to the database and reads the tt_content table... Since my app is already online I would rather like to parse the links withing my soap server class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the links is done in `typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/class.tslib_content.php` The method in question is `http_makelinks` in  (~ line 4780)

Links within the content have the following structure:

```
<link DESTINATION TARGET CLASS TITLE>your text</link>
```

Where DESTINATION can be

- a relative path to a file (e.g. PDF)
- an integer, then it links to an internal page
- an email, it get's prepended with `mailto:`
- an external link (including protocol)

(The other attributes are HTML attributes)

Unfortunately the class `tslib_content` has a lot of dependencies (also to typoscript of the current page template), so it's not feasible to instantiate it to use its methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I think this helps me a lot... allthough I will have to see how I can include this class since I do not have access to the typo3 classes so easily...

Comment: I suggest that you come up with your own method that would transofrm the links. The structure of the internal `<link>` tag has been given by @konsolenfreddy and its very unlikely to change in the branch 4 of TYPO3.